# How to obtain regression coefficients of a multiple linear regression model from simple linear regression models?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

Suppose I have a multiple linear regression model $$ Y=\beta_0+\beta_1X_1+\cdots+\beta_pX_p+\epsilon$$ 
How can I obtain the regression coefficients $\hat{\beta_i}$ by fitting just a series of simple linear regression models (additionally using sample means of the response/predictor variables if needed)?

Comment: Why would you? If this is homework, please use the self-study tag. Hint: you could search this site for "Frisch Waugh Lovell".

Comment: Alternatively, look into Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization.